# javafx 1.0 alignment and layout

Tags: javafx

With the JavaFX 1.0 release I am trying to layout some SwingButton instances in a HBox such that they are aligned to the right. A lot of the tutorials on the net (admittedly pre 1.0 release) talk about layout classes (FlowPanel et. al) which dont seem to be in this release. Whats the simplest way to achieve this seemingly simple task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two simpler ways to layout JavaFX components.

One is to use the JFXtras package which has a layout system (don't call it a manager :)) that is similar to Mig Layout:

http://code.google.com/p/jfxtras/

A second option is to layout your components using JFXBuilder from ReportMill:
http://www.reportmill.com/

JFXBuilder is the first true WYSWIG coding tool for JavaFX.

Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Haven't tested this, but other parts of the same tutorial works nicely.

http://java.sun.com/javafx/1/tutorials/ui/layout/index.html

Comment: Theres no ability to control alignment in HBox and VBox